# "setElevation" vs "setTranslationZ" vs "setZ"

Tags: android, shadow, android-elevation

Lollipop has all those new functions for the "View" class. What exactly are the differences between them, and why do we need so many functions for them?

I've read [**the docs**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), and I want to understand (or better understand) the difference and the need for each of them, so that I would know when to use each of them :

1. **elevation**

> base z depth of the view
>
> Must be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended
>   with a unit such as "14.5sp". Available units are: px (pixels), dp
>   (density-independent pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on preferred
>   font size), in (inches), mm (millimeters).
>
> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
>   "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.
>
> This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol elevation.

So this is what it starts from?

2. **translationZ**

> translation in z of the view. This value is added to its elevation.
>
> Must be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended
>   with a unit such as "14.5sp". Available units are: px (pixels), dp
>   (density-independent pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on preferred
>   font size), in (inches), mm (millimeters).
>
> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
>   "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.
>
> This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol translationZ.

So this is added in addition to the "elevation" ? Why is it needed?

3. And, the most confusing : **setZ**

> Sets the visual z position of this view, in pixels. This is equivalent
>   to setting the translationZ property to be the difference between the
>   x value passed in and the current elevation property.

I don't understand the explanation of this at all. Does this affect the shadow? What is it used for? To handle the case that 2 views have the same total elavation value ? Would Animating this value change the way a view is shown?